# Table header is repeating itself react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my render method in react class. data coming properly but header repeating it self.

How to arrange this block to render table in proper format.?

Here how it looks now [image: table]

i want only one time header should display.

```
render() {
    return (


        <div>
          {
            this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
              let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
              let d = dynamicData;
              return keys.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>

                    <table id="emp" border="1" class="table">
                       <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>UserId</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Desc</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead> 
                      <tbody >
                        <tr>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].employee_id}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].first_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].last_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].email}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].phone_number}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].hire_date}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].salary}</td>
                          {/* <td>{dynamicData[data].department.department_name}</td> */}
                          <td><button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.editClick}
                            className="btn  btn-primary btn-sm">Edit </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.handleClick}
                              className="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </button></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                );
              });
            })

          }
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your header is included within the `keys.map`, move it outside

Comment: Because your returning it every for every entry of array. keep it outside map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't Use header inside `map()` function to iterate

```
          <tbody >
          {this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
              let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
              let d = dynamicData;
              return keys.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
                        <tr>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].employee_id}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].first_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].last_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].email}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].phone_number}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].hire_date}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].salary}</td>
                          {/* <td>{dynamicData[data].department.department_name}</td> */}
                          <td><button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.editClick}
                            className="btn  btn-primary btn-sm">Edit </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.handleClick}
                              className="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </button></td>
                        </tr>
                  </div>
                );
              });
            })}
           </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
render() {
    return (
        <table id="emp" border="1" class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody >
          {
            this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
              let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
              let d = dynamicData;
              return keys.map(data => {
                return (
                  <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
                        <tr>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].employee_id}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].first_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].last_name}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].email}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].phone_number}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].hire_date}</td>
                          <td>{dynamicData[data].salary}</td>
                          {/* <td>{dynamicData[data].department.department_name}</td> */}
                          <td><button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.editClick}
                            className="btn  btn-primary btn-sm">Edit </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <button value={dynamicData[data].employee_id} onClick={this.handleClick}
                              className="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </button></td>
                        </tr>
                  </div>
                );
              });
            })

          }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data =[
  {company:"company",userId:'userId', role:'admin'},
  {company:"company2",userId:'userId2', role:'admin2'},
] 
const TableComponent = (props)=>{
  return (
   <div>
    <div> Table Component </div>
<table id="emp" border="1" class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Role</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
            {
              data.map((item)=>{
                 return <tr>
                          <td>{item.company}</td>
                          <td>{item.userId}</td>
                      <td>{item.role}</td>
              </tr>
              })
            }
            </tbody>
</table>
</div>
  )
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent/>,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Your are iterating `<thead>` with table data array. Just need to put it outside above map